# Countable Sums of Convergent Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Say we have a countable collection of absolutely convergent real series $\sum a_{1i}, \sum a_{2i}, \cdots$ converging respectively to the values $A_1,A_2,\cdots$. When does the combined series $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}$ converge, and what does it converge to? I'm assuming absolute convergence so that we don't have to worry about a precise ordering of the terms in the combined series.

My instinct is that the combined series converges if and only if the series $\sum A_i$ converges, and converges to the same value as that series, but I'm having trouble proving this. Is the same true if we let the $a_{ij}$ be complex?

Comment: I can't think of an elementary proof concerning only real analysis. But this can be proven using Fubini's theorem. The statement is: Let $(a_{jk})_{j,k\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Then $\sum_{j,k} a_{j,k} = \sum_j \left( \sum_k a_{jk} \right) = \sum_k \left( \sum_j a_{jk} \right)$ if at least one of them coverages with $|a_{jk}|$ in place of $a_{jk}$.

Comment: @JuliánVillaquirá I need to use this result to fill in a gap in Munkres' Analysis on Manifolds from before Fubini's Thm is introduced. I feel like there must be a more elementary way to do it.